# Nested UITableViews first tap issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I've got a main `UITableView` with other `UITableView`s within its `UITableViewCell`s.

The main table is not selectable. The inner tables are (single selection).

The issue: it works absolutely ok after the first tap, but **does not work in that first tap**. If that tap pushes another View Controller, if I then go back to the table, it works again, but some scrolling leads it to the wrong behavior again.

Any hint? Any idea on how to build nested tables successfully?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Can you not use a collection view? What is in each cell?

Comment: @Wain No I can not, it's hard to explain due to the complexity of my layout.

Comment: I've finally workarounded this issue by creating a category on `UITableViewCell`. It's got a method that I must call on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for every cell that contains an inner table.

What the method does is add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the table view, and there I catch the taps and call the `didSelectRowForIndexPath` manually.

Comment: Cool, can you add that as an answer and accept it ;-)

Comment: [«You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.»](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html) UITableViews are subclasses of UIScrollViews, so this applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally workarounded this issue by creating a category on `UITableViewCell`.

It's got a method that I must call on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for every cell that contains an inner table.

What the method does is add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the table view, and there I catch the taps and call the `didSelectRowForIndexPath` manually.